# My program always stop and I don't know why

Tags: python

I don't know what is happening the score always stop at 30 and do nothing.

```
import time
score = 0

def score_():
    global score
    score = score + 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
def something():
    X = 430
    Y = 130
    while score > 30:
        knifeX= X +10
        knifeY= Y +10
        time.sleep(1)
while True:
    score_()
    something()
    print(score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while score > 30:
    knifeX= X +10
    knifeY= Y +10
    time.sleep(1)
```

If score is 31 or higher, this loop will run forever, because nothing inside the loop changes score.

So the `something()` function will never end.